Can Airflow run a task which the excuetable is on another machine?
I am trying to schedule a process using Airflow, but for some reason, I cannot deploy the airflow and the script needs to be run on the same server (has to be in a different physical location due to some policy). Wonder if an airflow operator (i.e. pythonOperator) can call some script on another server with an IP address configured?
I think it's different than deploying jobs in multiple servers because the task has to be run on a specific server.

you can use the SSHoperator for running a command or a script on another server. for e.g.:
run_script = SSHOperator(ssh_conn_id='ssh-server',
    task_id='run_script',
    command='/path/to/script args',
    dag=dag,
   )


adding comment as an answer.
you can use the SSHoperator for running a command or a script on another server. Add a connection of type SSH for your server having the script. sample task code :
run_script = SSHOperator(
ssh_conn_id='ssh-server', 
task_id='run_script', 
command='/path/to/script script_args', 
dag=dag
)

